# FB Messenger: How can I send a message depending by last 2-3 replies

Tags: api, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I would like to do something like here: https://www.messenger.com/t/recipidea

Example - scenario:

```
1)
Page: "So tell me, what do you have in your fridge ?"
Reply: "milk"
2)
Page: "What else ?"
Reply: "banana"
3)
Page: "Hmmm milk and banana that looks yummy . Let me think a minute ... " ... And bellow show recipes...
```

Practicaly in the step 3) exists replies from 1) and 2). I would like to know how can i get last 2 replies in this step.

I suppose in step 2) is collected reply from step 1) and in step 3 what is in step 2).

Maybe an idea is by using payload and to collect here many data as string in limit of 1000 characters, but they send basic message as text, no buttons that have payload.

I would like to know is exists a solution without store messages on the server?

Have you idea how is made that ?

Thank You

Comment: you have to do that server side, there is no existing solution with the api itself

Answer (score 0):

Cache either the full user responses, or just the parts of the responses you need for later, server-side. Then you can use them to construct your response when appropriate.